# Search and return all index matching the first word in lua redis

Tags: lua, redis

`zscan id_name 0 match *t* count 100` will return all the indexes which as t in it.

My search index are like

```
zadd id_name 0  a:b
zadd id_name 0  t1:test
zadd id_name 0  a:test
zadd id_name 0  t2:b
```

I tried the following command

```
zscan id_name 0 match t*:t* count 10
```

the above commands returns only `t1:test`, but i also want `a:test t2:b` to be returned.

Is there any search command that achieves above requirement?

Comment: you forgot to ask a question. just in case you're waiting for an answer...

Comment: Sorry, Is there any command that matches my requirement?